# In pytorch, how to use the weight parameter in F.cross_entropy()?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

I'm trying to write some code like below:

```
x = Variable(torch.Tensor([[1.0,2.0,3.0]]))
y = Variable(torch.LongTensor([1]))
w = torch.Tensor([1.0,1.0,1.0])
F.cross_entropy(x,y,w)
w = torch.Tensor([1.0,10.0,1.0])
F.cross_entropy(x,y,w)
```

However, the output of cross entropy loss is always **1.4076** whatever **w** is. What is behind the weight parameter for F.cross_entropy()? How to use it correctly?
I'm using pytorch 0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `weight` parameter is used to compute a weighted result for all inputs based on their target class. If you have only one input or all inputs of the same target class, `weight` won't impact the loss.

See the difference however with 2 inputs of different target classes:

```python
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable

x = Variable(torch.Tensor([[1.0,2.0,3.0], [1.0,2.0,3.0]]))
y = Variable(torch.LongTensor([1, 2]))
w = torch.Tensor([1.0,1.0,1.0])
res = F.cross_entropy(x,y,w)
# 0.9076
w = torch.Tensor([1.0,10.0,1.0])
res = F.cross_entropy(x,y,w)
# 1.3167
```

Comment: I did not find an actual expression that show how the weights are used and the c++ is hard for me to decipher, any clues where I can find these details?

Comment: @pixelou: You can find the loss equation with `weights` in the `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss). You have the python implementation [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/22c169fb9cb618c660dab22edbe370c16a12a220/torch/nn/functional.py) otherwise.

Comment: My bad, I read this question too fast and though it was about the binary CE. You still answered my question though ;-) : in the python code you linked, it shows the latter uses point-wise weights instead of class-wise ones in pytorch.

Comment: @pixelou: Glad it helped nevertheless! :)